# Combining wedge products and tensor products

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

I am trying to express the wedge product $$p\wedge q\wedge r$$ into a sum of tensor products, where $p$, $q$, $r$ are one forms.

I know that  the wedge product $p \wedge q$ for one forms is $$p\wedge q= p\otimes q-q\otimes p.$$

Using the associative rule for wedge product, I get
$$p\wedge q\wedge r=(p \wedge q) \wedge r= (p\otimes q-q\otimes p)\wedge r.$$

How can I prodceed further? What rule tells us how to combine wedge products and tensor products?

I intuitively think the next step should be

$$(p\otimes q-q\otimes p)\wedge r= (p\otimes q) \wedge r-(q \otimes p)\wedge r,$$
but I am not sure if this is a valid operation.

Comment: I think that you can apply the tensor formula to the wedge with $r$ as well by using the expression in the brackets as your left factor and $r$ as the other one. Then use properties of tensor products.

Comment: @mandella Could you write it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: I gave a hint as to how to proceed, I am not sure it qualifies as an answer!

Comment: @mandella Do you mean $(p \otimes q - q\otimes p) \wedge r = (p\otimes q-q\otimes p) \otimes r  - r \otimes (p\otimes q-q\otimes p)$? But from my understanding, the formula $p \wedge q=p\otimes q-q\otimes p$ is for one forms. I dont think $(p \otimes q - q\otimes p)$ is a one form.

Comment: How do you define tensor product of one-forms?

Comment: @Berci My understanding is that $p \otimes q \equiv p() q()$ where each one form takes a vector argument and produce a number.